# How to build boost examples for python C++ embedding

Tags: python, c++, boost, embedding

Atm I need to wrap a C++ library to be usable in python code. For this I've it seems it's best to use boost python extension/wrapper. But right now I've constant problems with compilation of every example shown in documentation. I was able to make it run combination of python27 and boost_1_55 but anything never (python34 boost_1_58) seems to do not work. Following are error messages from building 2 basic examples (I'm running windows7 64bit):

**General Test**

```
C:\boost_1_59_0_b1\libs\python\example\quickstart>C:\boost_1_59_0_b1\bjam.exe toolset=msvc-12.0 --verbose-test test_ext
Performing configuration checks

- 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : no  (cached)
- mips1                    : no  (cached)
- power                    : no  (cached)
- sparc                    : no  (cached)
- x86                      : yes (cached)
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1923 targets...
...updating 4 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd
Creating library bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb and object
bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1207: incompatible PDB format in 'C:\boost_1_59_0_b1\libs\
python\example\quickstart\bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb'; delete and rebuild

    call "C:\Users\XY\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_12.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd" >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /NOENTRY /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd" /IMPLIB:"bi
n\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"   @
"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd.rsp"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pyd     bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb...
...removing bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\extending.pdb
...skipped <pbin\test_ext.test\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>test_ext for lack
of <pbin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>extending.pyd...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 2 targets...
```

**Embedding example:**

```
C:\boost_1_59_0_b1\libs\python\example\quickstart>C:\boost_1_59_0_b1\bjam.exe toolset=msvc-12.0 --verbose-test embedding
Performing configuration checks

- 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : no  (cached)
- mips1                    : no  (cached)
- power                    : no  (cached)
- sparc                    : no  (cached)
- x86                      : yes (cached)
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1992 targets...
...updating 3 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\embedding.obj
embedding.cpp
embedding.cpp(56) : error C2065: 'initembedded_hello' : undeclared identifier

call "C:\Users\XY\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_12.0_vcvarsall_x86.cm
d" >nul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\embedding.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi\embedding.obj...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>embedding.exe for lack of <pbin
\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>embedding.obj...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>embedding.pdb for lack of <pbin
\msvc-12.0\debug\threading-multi>embedding.obj...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 2 targets...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with the boost-python tutorial.  I think the cause is that I don't have the debug version of the python library.  To get round this I added the property `variant=release` to my invocation of b2.  This resolved my problem with incompatible pdb files though a better option would be getting the debug build of python.  Unfortunately, it only led me to further build errors!

Comment: Well I've ended up using cython for this C++ wrap up and ditched the boost completly.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing the same! :)